# Using LiveData in ViewModel to pass object to other activity

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to pass data from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity` using a MutableLiveData in a ViewModel,, the following code gives me a NullPointerException when SecondActivity tries to access the LiveData

ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
val current=MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    textView.text="test"
    viewModel.current.value="test"
    textView.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java))
    }
}}
```

SecondActivity:

```
class SecondActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
    textView2.text = viewModel.current.value!! // NullPointerException
}}
```

Comment: The reason for NPE is that if you want to share `ViewModel` between views, you need to have a context of your previous view in order to retrieve the `ViewModel` that was bound to the previous view.

Comment: If you can I would recomend using single Activity. In that care you can share `ViewModel` as @Francesc answered bellow. Then you can also use navigation component etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewmodel` in your second `Activity` is not the same as that on the 1st `Activity`; there is a cache of `ViewModel`s by owner (the activities in this case), and these owners are different in each case.

`ViewModel`s can be used to share data between `Fragment`s on the same `Activity`, but they don't work for sharing data between activities. For that, pass the data in the `Intent` to start the 2nd `Activity` (if lightweight), otherwise store it in some long lived object.

```
val intent = Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("KEY", "<string to pass here>")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: long lived object ? you mean like a singleton ?

Comment: Something that lives longer than the activity, maybe a Singleton, or something you can instantiate in one activity and free in the next, once the data is retrieved. Or you could store it in a DB, or in shared preferences, ... many solutions based on your specific requirements.